# How to do change the recieved SQL output format, in python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

All i want to simple text and output from sql query used in python

```
    import psycopg2
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='news' user='postgres'")
    print("On which days did more than 1% of requests lead to errors? \n")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT *FROM(SELECT date(time), round((count(status) FILTER (WHERE 
     NOT status ='200 OK'))::numeric * 100 / count(status), 2) AS 
     error_percentage FROM log GROUP BY date(time) ORDER BY error_percentage 
     DESC) AS I WHERE error_percentage > 1;" )

     results = cursor.fetchall()
     print (results)
     conn.close()
```

[image: This is the output what i am getting.]

What i exactly want output like this.......

On which days did more than 1% of requests lead to errors?
[ July 17, 2016 — 2.27% errors]

Comment: Read the docs about `str.format()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix your sql: make one string in the form you want it to be.
Something like

```
select to_char(date(time), 'FMDay, FMDD, FMYear') + " - " + to_char(dec_value) + "% errors"
```

Otherwise you will get array as return.

Comment: But if i use to_char for decimal value, then i wont be able to use where clause. Which is mentioned in last line of sql query

Comment: Make to_char on second level of select (the upper one)